# Sum of an exponential function/Mathematica

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematica

I have a function that looks like following:
$$T=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos(\lambda_n x)}{\lambda_n}\exp(-\lambda_n^2 t)$$
where $\lambda_n=\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}$. I use Mathematica to plot $T$ as a function of $x$ in the range of {x,0,1} for different $t$ values. The solution when $t=0$ and $t=\infty$ appears correctly. However, for all values $0<t<\infty$ the software keeps running. I am wondering if the exponential function has a special command to use in Mathematica or I am missing something in my code.  
 
Here is my Mathematica syntax:

```
Plot[Simplify[ Abs[2 Sum[((-1)^(n - 1) Cos[((2 n - 1) [Pi])/2 x])/(((2 n - 1) [Pi])/2) Exp[-(((2 n - 1) [Pi])/2)^2 (t)], {n, 1, Infinity}]], Assumptions -> {x > 0}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Lama

Comment: You had an unescaped `<` outside of MathJax or a code markup. So the parser interpreted that as the start of a HTML tag. An invalid tag that was never closed, but HTML parsers are used to just ignore such niceties as correct syntax [the web would be less than half as large as it is if they refused incorrect syntax], and go on nevertheless. But of course tags aren't rendered.

Answer (score 0):

When $\,t=0\,$:
$$ T=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos\left(\lambda_n\,x\right)}{\lambda_n} = \frac{2}{\pi}\left[\arctan\left({\large e}^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}x}\right)+\arctan\left({\large e}^{+i\frac{\pi}{2}x}\right)\right] $$ 
And this is a famous [square wave](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B2%2FPi%5D+%5BArcTan%5BExp%5B-I+x+Pi%2F2%5D%5D%2BArcTan%5BExp%5B%2BI+x+Pi%2F2%5D%5D%5D) function.  
 
  
 
When $\,x=1\,$:
$$ T=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos\left(\lambda_n\right)}{\lambda_n}\,{\large e}^{-\lambda_n^2\,t} = \color{red}{0} \quad\text{for all }t\quad\left\{{\small\cos\left((2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0}\right\} $$ 
  
 
Noticing the series is rapid convergent, exploiting Mathematica defining functions capabilities,  
 
Perhaps it will be better to define a function $\,f(x,t,l)\,$ As shown below,
 
 
And start plotting multiple graphs for different values of $\,t\,$ at the same time. Enjoy!

```
f[x_, t_, l_] := 2 Sum[((-1)^(n - 1)) Cos[(((2 n - 1) Pi)/2) x] Exp[-((((2 n - 1) Pi)/2)^2) t]/(((2 n - 1) Pi)/2), {n, 1, l}];
Plot[{f[x, 0/4, 100], f[x, 1/4, 100], f[x, 2/4, 100], f[x, 3/4, 100], f[x, 4/4, 100], f[x, 5/4, 100]}, {x, -1, +1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now that's a beauty!! Many thanks for your help!!!